# How to remove the Pinned tiles in Start Menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

In Windows 10, every time I open the start menu, I come across the section "Pinned Tiles"

[image]

Is there a way to remove this section or to assign as default the section "All apps",

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Settings`>`Personalization`>`Start` and turn the "Show app list in Start menu" on.

[image]

And now the Start menu looks like this

[image]